# Function body identification in programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, function, visual-c++, automation

I am trying to create automation tool to insert comment line above function body. Idea is, I will read .CPP file as text and will find function body. Once function body found in .CPP file then i will put function header above function body.

Reading and writing of file will work similar to normal text file but I want to know generalized function body definition. I.e. how I will find function body in .CPP file programmatically. Else is there is any alternative to put function header above function body.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe hook in some C++ parser (e.g. clang)?

Comment: @Niall: Thanks for reply but can you please provide some idea about kind of parser you talking about. I'm very new in automation Stuff.:)

Comment: You could identify where `{` and `}` is, and if it's not preceded by some other thing that uses it, like an `if` or `for` or whatever, then it's a function body?

Comment: Also, could you possibly edit in an example of what you are aiming to achieve. Personally, I'm having trouble understanding your aim.

Comment: Maybe a nice place to start is http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html and then maybe the code for the clang formatter as a sample?

Comment: I have used a tool called http://gccxml.github.io in the past which works very well for these kind of things. It will convert your .cpp file into a xml file and you can then easily iterate over all function bodies in the xml file (for example with libxml2). Every xml element will contain an attribute where the definition/implementation for that element (i.e. file and line number) was found.

Comment: This is a bit broad as a question since there are many possible way of addressing it

Comment: I don't think this is possible without being able to completely parse c++ files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the idea:

Find first open brace {.
Then find matching closing brace.
Repeat it

```
public List<string> FindFunctions(string str)
{
    var ret = new List<string>();
    var position = 0;
    var goout = false;

    while (!goout)
    {
        position = str.IndexOf("{", position);
        if (position == -1)
            break;
        var str1 = GetBracedString(str.Substring(position), '{', '}','"');
        position += str1.Length;
        ret.Add(str1);
    }
    return ret;
}




public String GetBracedString(string str, char openB, char closeB, char quoteChar)
{
    int i = 0;
    var goout = false;
    int index = -1;
    var isUnpairedQoute = new Func<string, char, bool>((s, q) => s.Count(x => x == q)%2 == 1);
    var braceMatch = new Func<string, char, char, bool>((s,o,c) => s.Count(x => x == o) == s.Count(x => x == c));
    while (!goout)
    {
        index = str.IndexOf(closeB, index + 1);
        var testS = str.Substring(0, index + 1);
        index = isUnpairedQoute(testS,quoteChar) ? str.IndexOf(quoteChar, index) : index;
        testS = str.Substring(0, index + 1);
        testS = Regex.Replace(testS, String.Format("{0}.*?[{1}{2}]+?.*?{0}", quoteChar, openB, closeB),match => new string('#', match.Value.Length));
        goout = braceMatch(testS,openB,closeB);
    }
    return str.Substring(0, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: What about `for` loops? Or `while` loops. Or `if`. Or {braces} because {I feel like it} and it {does nearly the same thing}? I knew someone who put braces on every line of code because he didn't know any better. Everything was local in scope to that line, but the monstrosity compiled.

Comment: Well, I suppose that the very first curly brace will belong to beginning of the function body. Also, it's matching curly brace will be the end of function body ...

Comment: That's assuming that you only want to match one function in a file.

Comment: @Yann4 Please, check source code and the explanation. Pay attention to  "the matching closing brace".

Comment: I'm not quite following the line above `goout = true`, so you might well be right.

Comment: testS.Count(x => x == openB) counts all the occurences of openB char in testS string

Comment: This solution also fails when braces are within quoted strings.

Comment: @JoriO You are right, but I just gave an idea to start, all of these special cases could be handled easily

Comment: @manda I don't think these 'special' cases are so easy. In order to know which blocks are function bodies and which are not, you must be able to parse the whole file.

Comment: @JoriO Ok mister, I have edited my code for you to include this special case.

Comment: @manda The problem is that we're trying to write a C++ parser. How about `namespace`, or `static` member variables initialized with an initializer list?

Comment: @manda Ok, if you insist on going your way: how about escapized double-quotes? Or brace-characters in single quotes? And remember to include JonathanMee's cases. If they 'can be handled easily' as you said, I'm sure you will provide us them, too. Or you could just admit that you were wrong this time :)

Comment: @manda If you were to write us more code, then I'll allow you to peek into future. There I can see comments, which include such words as 'class', 'struct' and even 'preprocessor'.

Comment: Well, I can, if you prefer, make complete solution on this, but this would take time. I think that the idea, in this case, is not to bring the complete solution, but just to give a direction. Am I missing something? I would rather be happy if you said that the presented idea is bad in the root, then giving the breaking cases for my peace of code